# Responsive 2 column staggered layout client expectations vs reality problem

Tags: responsive

In a bit of an urgent bummer at the problem, we developed and delivered a Wordpress site with blog post layouts that are split in 2 columns via Gutenberg built in columns, on desktop, the site appears like a magazine, where users read items from left col to right, and then left to right again, as per the numbering on my attached diagram.

However in mobile, as per usual, one entire column would stack on the other one, hence the order is off.

Is there a way to actually pull this off? To have that ordered content in a wordpress blog post and be able to allow client to create those posts in the CMS.

I know the obvious method would be masonry layouts, but to my knowledge, no theme/plugin allows you to enter blog posts with a mixed media in ordered masonry blocks.

[image]

[image: the problem]

Comment: I recall seeing something in CSS that allows for reordering of specific divs - pulling one ahead of another... maybe in Bootstrap or could have been CSS3 flex. I can't recall the details, but this post might help: [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/179419/160457](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/179419/160457)

Comment: yeah for flex, it's the order property. In fact, in bootstrap you can even target specific order for specific breakpoints. Thing is I can't really enter the content in such a way within Wordpress.. If it were a standalone landing page, no problem.

Comment: Why can't it be incorporated in the WordPress loop?

Comment: coz this is for a blog post article.. as in the actual post content. Not listing out posts.

Comment: added a screenshot of the actual page that has been realised now, replaced with dummy content.

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought 1/2/3/4/5/6/7 were posts, not separate parts of the same post. If you are using Gutenberg to make each post, can you not manipulate the CSS output of it to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: If I were using Gutenberg I would write you a full answer with examples, but I don't have it activated on any installation so I can't show you a direct example. This is partly why I am writing in the comments section rather than posting an answer.

Comment: This link may help you: [https://css-tricks.com/styling-the-gutenberg-columns-block/](https://css-tricks.com/styling-the-gutenberg-columns-block/)

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a working solution for now, which is to input everything as a 'flat' no column post, this way the 'flow' of the content when the client is entering is exactly how it would be on mobile.

On Desktop, I apply width:50% and masonry plugin to all direct child elements of the post-body container.

On Mobile breakpoints in CSS, I make the child elements width 100%.

It's working well for now, although as usual, certain combinations of block heights might result in unexpected layouts.